# maskMoney Jquery Bug when using append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masking

I have html like this, actually input inside tr of table:

```
<input type='text' class='angka1' style='text-align:right;' name='Nominal"+a+"' required/>
```

And i have a javascript like this in when document ready:

[image]

When i try to append just 1 row, nothing wrong, i can input number formatted correctly. But, when i try to append more than 1, like 2 rows, i try to input '1'. than i will get '11'.

I get word like long of the row i have inputted. How can i fix it?, or do you have any solution to create object formatted like `#.###,##`. (Sorry many of tags in html i deleted, i am very beginner in stackoverflow)

Comment: Paste code not image

Comment: I can't understand it. Was easier to upload an image of your code rather than the actual code?!

Comment: i tried to paste the code, but i can't post it because i get a warning from stackoverflow.

Comment: @Satpal i have editted the picture, i hope you can read it better.

Comment: @AlexChar i have editted the picture, i hope you can read it better.

Comment: It should be `$('.angka' + i).maskMoney()` instead of `$('.angka1').maskMoney()`

Comment: @Satpal i have tried it to my code, and i still get the same result. when i try to append to 2 rows, i still get the double results.

Comment: @Satpal oh, no, you are right man, Try to post your post, and i will give vote to your post, i got wrong, i should to post, before the increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$('.angka' + i).maskMoney()` instead of `$('.angka1').maskMoney()` and move statement `i++` after the statement